# How to retrieve server certificate info during HTTPS negotiation‏ in IWebBrowser control

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, https, security, iwebbrowser2

I understood *HTTPS* is like *HTTP*, a built-in *APP*(protocol handler) supported in IE web browser control (i.e. the *IWebBrowser2*).

When creating a HTML application using *IWebBrowser2* control for loading web content, during the *HTTPS* handshake negotiation, I want the app to verify certain common fields presented in server certificate which the app trying to communicate, and stop sending out sensitive info when found certificate suspicious.

Is there any way I can achieve this with known *IWebBrowser2* control interfaces, methods or overriding *HTTPS* protocol handler somewhat, or register a callback for custom actions like ServerCertificateValidationCallback in managed code?

Any helpful info and feedback are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.